# Set Vue prop's default to parent's options

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a child component that needs to accept a value given in the component's parent's `$options` object as a possible default value.

Background: The component shall be able to get its data via a prop or from a config. But there is legacy code that relies on the data being passed as an option to the main Vue instance.

The new method to create the Vue instance is this:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(MainComp, { 
        props: {
            document: 'data.json'
        }
    })
});
```

And the component takes care of deriving the prop's value from the config file if it's not provided (or sets it to the ultimate default value `null`):

```
import Config from './config.js';
[...]    
props: {
    document: {
        default: Config.document || null
    },
```

That works beautifully.

However, in the legacy code the instance used to be created like this:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    document: 'data.json',
    render: h => h(MainComp)
});
```

and the data was passed in the `data()` function by calling `this.$parent.$options['document']`.

My first idea was to add this very same code to the new `default`:

```
default: this.$parent.$options['document'] || Config.document || null
```

but obviously it doesn't work, because [as the docs say](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation) "props are validated before a component instance is created, so instance properties [are not] available".

So I tried specifying my "special default" via the `data()` function like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        document: document || this.$parent.$options['document']
    };
},
```

But then, Vue rightfully complains: "The data property "document" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead."

How do I solve this vicious circle?

Comment: So ... use this last example, with data returning document, but do not send it to this component as prop? Or disable props inheritance with inheritAttrs: false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
default: () => this.$parent.$options['document'] || Config.document || null
```

Comment: I didn't bother trying a function because the docs I cited in my question say that "instance properties [...] will not be available inside default or validator functions", and `$parent` [*is* an instance property](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Properties). Nevertheless I tried your code - no luck at first :( But then I rewrote the arrow function to a standard one, i.e. `default: function() { return this.$parent.$options['document'] || Config.document || null }` and **it worked**! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that ;-) @Christallkeks